# Play 2.6: Encoding url parameters

Tags: scala, playframework, url-encoding

I have something like the following URL:

```
http://www.123.com/api/link/http://www.bla.com/?contenId=123&User=test
```

But i know it needs to be encoded to be valid. Is there a way to encode it to be on the right format, something like the following:

```
http://www.123.com/api/link/http%3a%2f%2fwww.bla.com%2f%3fcontenId%3d123%26User%3dtest
```

Comment: Not clear what you need... are you having troubles wit play-ws maybe?

Comment: not play-ws its simple app,i want the url's data to be encrypted  when for example sign in or send a form data to the server.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `import java.net.URLEncoder` for encoding URLs and/or `import java.netURLDecoder` for decoding the encoded urls.

For encoding URL:

```
import java.net.URLEncoder
val urlEncoded = URLEncoder.encode("https://encodeMe", "UTF-8")
```

For decoding URL:

```
import java.net.URLDecoder
val urlDecoded = URLDecoder.decode("http%3a%2f%2fwww.bla.com", "UTF-8")
```

Also look at the following note, in the library, regarding the `UTF-8`.

> Note: The World Wide Web Consortium Recommendation states that UTF-8 should be used. Not doing so may introduce incompatibilities.

Comment: thanks Dave, but how the browser will  get the encoded url from the back-end, it seems to be just a variable on a class.

Comment: @mohamedali10 In your controller you use http responses, such as Ok, BadRequest, etc. no? So, you pass these vals to them instead of a url; something like MovePermanently("http://service2.com/?servicecalling="+urlEncoded). Then the encoded url will be used. However I have to say this type of approach is when the target service knows that you are passing an encoded url.